TCP/IP Communication Slower in Standalone Executable Compared to F5 Debug in Release Mode (C#)
I’m experiencing an unexpected issue with TCP/IP communication speed in a C# application developed in Visual Studio. When I run the application in Release mode using F5 (Start Debugging) in Visual Studio, the TCP/IP communication performs as expected and at an optimal speed. However, when I run the compiled standalone executable directly by double-clicking the file (outside of Visual Studio), the TCP/IP communication noticeably slows down. This is puzzling since all conditions, configurations, and code are identical between the two cases.
Has anyone encountered this issue, and what steps might I take to ensure consistent TCP/IP communication speed in both execution scenarios? Are there specific settings or configurations to adjust, or known factors that could cause this difference? Any insights or recommendations for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated!
IDE: Visual Studio 2022(Release Mode)
Execution Methods:
Running through Visual Studio with F5 in Release mode (faster TCP/IP speed)
Running the compiled executable directly (slower TCP/IP speed)
Environment: All other conditions, including network environment, machine specifications, and code, are identical.
Steps Already Tried:
Increased the program's priority to ensure it receives adequate resources.
Disabled antivirus and Windows Defender real-time protection when running the standalone executable, but the slower TCP/IP performance persists.
Noteworthy Observations:
When I first run the program with F5 and then subsequently launch the standalone executable, the standalone executable’s TCP/IP speed improves.
Conversely, if I run the standalone executable first and then launch the program with F5, both speed of the program experience slower TCP/IP speeds.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
